# PHP Included file is not echoing to markup

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to retrieve a set of values from a database using PHP, and then I would like to pass those retrieved values to javascript, so that they can be displayed to the user, used to construct other elements, etc.

Javascript in Index.php:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function($) {
  $(document).ready( function() {
    var $img = $("#image1").imgNotes2({
      onReady: function() {
        var notes = [<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/inc/mapmarkers.php'; ?>]
        this.import(notes);
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

And mapmarkers.php;

```
<?php

require '../assets/setup/mapdb.inc.php';
    
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE id >= 1;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            // SQL ERROR
            return false;
        }
        else {
            
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            
            $index = 0;
            $string = "";
            
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                $MarkerInfo = array(
                    'id' => $row['id'],
                    'author' => $row['author'],
                    'party' => $row['party'],
                    'permission' => $row['permission'],
                    'enabled' => $row['enabled'],
                    'xpos' => $row['xpos'],
                    'ypos' => $row['ypos']
                );
                
                echo ($MarkerInfo);
            }
        }
?>
```

Currently, Index.php loads and runs just fine but none of the output from mapmarkers.php is actually echoed into the script tag. What have I mucked up?

I am including mapmarkers.php because of security reasons but if there is another safe way to do this please let me know.

Looked around quite a bit and couldn't truly find anyone else with this exact problem, apologies in advance if this has already been asked/solved.

Comment: use print_r or var_dump instead of echo for arrays.
and you are using same key for all those array values. It will overwrite existing values

Comment: Have you tried checking the page HTML source? Why are all your array keys `"id"`?

Comment: Turn on [php error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). You are trying to echo array. Your array has same index for all values. ...?

Comment: Lots of errors... 1) Your prepared statement has no parameters so `bind_param` will fail. 2) `$selector` is not defined. 3) You're overwriting `$MarkerInfo` on each loop. 4) You're using the same array key for all properties. 5) You're trying to echo an array on each loop. 6) The output will not be valid JavaScript

Comment: What helped me a lot was [this tutorial from Google about maps using PHP and MySQL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps)

Comment: I tried to make the source a little more readable, the reuse of the 'id' key was a mistake introduced in that effort. In response to Phil, As far as overwriting $MarkerInfo on each loop, it's my understanding that that is both necessary and what I want to occur, since I am hoping to retrieve an unknown amount of entries from the database, and want to add all of them to the scripts array. I also understand that it won't yet be valid javascript, I know how to solve that, but for the moment I cannot even get an echo output of any sort from mapmarkers.php. I am looking into #1 and #2 at the moment

Comment: From Phil's comment, #1 and #2 can both be solved by simply removing the mysqli_stmt_bind_param line since I am not using any parameters in my SQL query - however doing so still does not result in an echo.

Comment: You can't echo an array. What you should do is put all the results in a container array, e.g. `$results[] = $MarkerInfo;`. Then use `echo json_encode($results);` at the end of the loop, instead of echoing during each iteration.

Comment: What is `mysql_fetch_assoc`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS so it doesn't wrap the include in square brackets:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function($) {
  $(document).ready( function() {
    var $img = $("#image1").imgNotes2({
      onReady: function() {
        var notes = <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/home/inc/mapmarkers.php'; ?>;
        this.import(notes);
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Then change the PHP script so it echoes all the results as JSON, which will be a valid JavaScript literal.

```
<?php

require '../assets/setup/mapdb.inc.php';
    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE id >= 1;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    // SQL ERROR
    return false;
}
else {
    
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
    $index = 0;
    $string = "";
    $results = [];
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $MarkerInfo = array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'author' => $row['author'],
            'party' => $row['party'],
            'permission' => $row['permission'],
            'enabled' => $row['enabled'],
            'xpos' => $row['xpos'],
            'ypos' => $row['ypos']
        );
        
        $results[] = $MarkerInfo;
    }
    echo json_encode($results);
}
?>
```

Comment: I did exactly as is outlined here and in the comments on the OP in regards to encoding using json_encode with an added $results[] container array - however nothing has changed. The resulting script tag has only code in it up until the <?PHP tag, everything after that point is not added to the script (meaning I'm losing a portion of my script somehow) and I still do not get any kind of echo from mapmarkers.php. Specifically "var notes =" is at the end of the resulting script. Nothing after that is added / echoed.

Comment: Check your PHP error log to make sure it's finding all the include files.